# User with no questions / answers get association bonus?

Tags: bug, association-bonus

There is a user: [Dark Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6229006/dark-knight?tab=reputation)

They have the association bonus on four sites, but I can't see why? They don't seem to have any accounts that meet the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

> One of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus.

Comment: Probably a deleted account. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks. :) my phrasing was obviously just slightly off.

Comment: Hah. That user has now been destroyed, it seems.